# Google Drive SDK: batch requests of get_media results in HttpError 303

Tags: python, google-drive-api

I'm trying to batch a several `get_media` calls into a single requests. These `get_media` requests seems to be working fine when I run them one at a time, but when batched together I'm getting a 303 / 'the document has moved' error.

Here's my code:

```
batch = connection.new_batch_http_request()
for file in some_list: 
    batch.add(connection.files().get_media(fileId = file['id'], callback = ...)

batch.execute()
```

My callback has the signature `callback(request_id, response, exception)`, and in this case I'm receiving an exception of type `googleapiclient.errors.HttpError`, with:

- Content: `<HTML><HEAD><TITLE>See Other</TITLE></HEAD><BODY BGCOLOR="#FFFFFF" TEXT="#000000"><H1>See Other</H1>The document has moved <A HREF="https://www.googleapis.com/download/drive/v2/files/0B...UW8?alt=media">here</A>.</BODY></HTML>`
- response.location: `https://www.googleapis.com/download/drive/v2/files/0B...UW8?alt=media`
- response.status: 303

Any idea why this is happening?

Note that:

- As stated above, the `get_media` calls work fine when executed one-by-one (not in batch).
- I've also tried to batch several `get` requests together, and this seems to be working fine.

Comment: Can you put the complete error message? What kind of files are you requesting for media?

Comment: I'm getting this error for various types of files. I'm editing the original question to add information about the error I'm getting.

Comment: The httpt 303 code is for redirection. Usually browsers or libraries handle this code to get to the location described in the response. As you are doing this in a batch request, the batch is getting this response but is not doing the redirection. Instead you will have to make the call to the location you are getting to retrieve the information. It would be difficult to know why this is happening since that is Google's internal functionality. https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/199KcbAn7mY4NSEPM13NhlVSuWmQq1LDHn6V28X7Oj3Y/edit#gid=0

Comment: Making another http request for every document beats the purpose of the match mechanism. As I wrote in the question, making get_media calls one by one works fine - if that's the solution, there's absolutely no value to using batch. Btw - I don't have access to the link you shared.

Comment: my bad, this is the link i wanted to share https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_303  you are correct, making a new request for every file would beat the purpose of the batch request. But in general the purpose of the batch request is to reduce the traffic in a network by combining many small operations, and if you are going to ask for file content it would also beat the purpose of the batch request. https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/python/guide/batch

Answer (score 1):

Google say this isn't supported. See (very few) additional details [here](https://code.google.com/a/google.com/p/apps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=4104).

Comment: This is also mentioned in https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/batch - "Note: Currently, Google Drive does not support batch operations for media, either for upload or download." The Google Drive API seems have special case after special case for everything...